# Requests from referer are blocked for accessing Google API

Tags: php, google-api

We used the third-party web app and tried to integrate this Google API for Translation.

Currently, it's working OK. We can call the API to do the translation.

However, when we started to restrict this by using the HTTP REFERRER. We keep getting: *Requests from referer are blocked.*

On the URL, we tried the combination below and no luck:

```
*.ourdomainname.com/*
ourdomainname.com/*
```

The developer helped us to identify this and come up with this error detail:

```
Requests from referer <empty> are blocked.
```

Any ideas? Currently, it's working OK if we are not putting any restrictions, which is not good :) We prefer to restrict this.

I'm appreciated your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: So send a referrer with your request then ...? You only tagged this `php`, as far as languages go, so I assume you are making this API request from the server side - so you should be in full control over what you want to send as referrer.

Comment: @CBroe - As we are relying on the third-party developer, I would imagine that the code needs to pass "HTTP-referrer" then when calling the API. I thought this was done automatically by the client app. Is that correct?

Comment: That depends entirely on the app. And since the referrer technically is the previously visited URL, an app outside of a web context might not send one at all by default, when making HTTP requests.

Comment: @CBroe - we use the web app. It should have the HTTP referrer, then. Would Cloudflare get nothing to do with this? We use CloudFlare for our domain registrar as well as name servers with all features that they have.

Comment: What web app? This is about something _you_ implemented, no?

Comment: @CBroe - correct ... it's a custom web app we own and implement.

Comment: Is your app limiting sending of a referrer via a `Referrer-Policy` perhaps?

Comment: @CBroe - we raised this to the third-party web app developer, and they don't have this Referrer-Policy as you mentioned, as they have other clients using similar web apps - no issue. Would be something to do with **Cloudflare** that we use? Cloudflare acts as an intermediary between a client and a server, using a reverse proxy to mirror and cache websites. We might try to by pass this to see what's happened.

Comment: @CBroe - we disabled Cloudflare and will go straight to the server. We tested called this Google API via the web app, and it's the same thing.  So we don't believe this related Referer-Policy if there is any on this Cloudflare.